# How to include locally build Python package system-wide?

Tags: package-management, python

For example: I build `numpy` with Intel MKL libraries and it's available in Python shell, but if I want to install some package from repository that depends on `numpy`, my build is not considered.

What would be easiest way to include my Python build package in Ubuntu, so that packages from repository can find it, preferably without building again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to build a deb file and install it.

Checkinstall will replace de 'make install' part of the standard compilation. Instead of just copying the files to their target directories it will build and install a deb file.

If you can't use checkinstall, you could create a dummy package using equivs. Note that this can create problems when updating or uninstalling and it's only recommended for expert users. It has a known tendency to grow out of control, so use it with care.

Install equivs:

```
sudo apt-get install equivs
```

Create the control file:

```
equivs-control python-numpy
```

This will create a template control file called python-numpy (the name doesn't matter)edit it python-numpy so it looks like this:

```
### Commented entries have reasonable defaults.
### Uncomment to edit them.
# Source: <source package name; defaults to package name>
Section: misc
Priority: optional
# Homepage: <enter URL here; no default>
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: python-numpy
Version: 9.9
# Maintainer: Your Name <yourname@example.com>
# Pre-Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Recommends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Suggests: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Provides: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Replaces: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Architecture: all
# Copyright: <copyright file; defaults to GPL2>
# Changelog: <changelog file; defaults to a generic changelog>
# Readme: <README.Debian file; defaults to a generic one>
# Extra-Files: <comma-separated list of additional files for the doc directory>
# Files: <pair of space-separated paths; First is file to include, second is destination>
#  <more pairs, if there's more than one file to include. Notice the starting space>
Description: <short description; defaults to some wise words> 
 long description and info
 .
 second paragraph
```

The more data that you give to it, the better the deb will be. I have only modified 2 fields:

- Package: The name of the package that you want to build. For a dirty solution use python-pynum
- Version: Use a number high enough to keep apt-get from updating it.

A better (but untested by me) solution could be to create a different package name, something link python-pynum-dummy, and use in the Provides line put python-numpy. This should be cleaner.

Finally build the deb.

```
equivs-build python-numpy
```

And install it.

Comment: `checkinstall` can't handle packages which change easy-install.pth

Comment: Umm... I'm lost. A package installed by a deb file shouldn't touch easy-install.pth. Only packages installed with easy-install should.

Comment: I used `checkinstall` before, and if setup system by arbitrary python package writes to easy-install.pth (read: use setuptools),  `checkinstall` fails. Not all packages write to easy-install.pth, but many do, and I'm not aware of workaround

Comment: Then you can must use debbuild to build a proper .deb file. You can also make a dummy package to trick apt-get, but it could cause problems with updates or when uninstalling. I will try to expand it later.

Comment: OK, thanks. Dummy package sounds great. Right now, I'm not interested in proper debs as that is too complicated to make for every package I install